# On change disable/enable fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to disable/enable fields while choosing a result from a dropdown menu. When `type1` is chosen it should show all fields, `type2` it should disable the dropdown menu and `type3` should also disable the extra field.

```
<select id="TType">
    <option value="type1">Full</option>
    <option value="type2">Show less</option>
    <option value="type3">Show even less</option>
</select>

<input type="text" maxlength="5" id="customer" name="customer">
<input type="text" maxlength="10" id="extra" name="extra">
<select id="city" name="city">
    <option value="0"> - </option>
    <option value="1">New York</option>
    <option value="2">Chicago</option>
    <option value="3">London</option>
    <option value="4">Athens</option>
</select>
```

And here is the javascript I'm trying to use

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("select").on("change", function(){
    var formId = $(this).attr("value");
    if(formId == "type1"){
      $("input[type=text]").each(function(){
        var inputId = $(this).attr("id");
        if(inputId == "customer" || inputId == "extra"){
          $(this).prop("disabled",false);
          $(this).prop("required",true);
        }
      })
      $("select").each(function(){
        var inputId = $(this).attr("id");
        if(inputId == "city"){
          $(this).prop("disabled",false);
          $(this).prop("required",true);
        }
      })
    }else if(formId == "type2"){
      $("select").each(function(){
        var inputId = $(this).attr("id");
        if(inputId == "city"){ 
          $(this).prop("disabled",true);
        }
      })
    }else if(formId == "type3"){
      $("select").each(function(){
        var inputId = $(this).attr("id");
        if(inputId == "city"){ 
          $(this).prop("disabled",true);
        }
      })
      $("input[type=text]").each(function(){
        var inputId = $(this).attr("id");
        if(inputId == "extra"){
          $(this).prop("disabled",true);
        }else{
          $(this).prop("disabled",false);
          $(this).prop("required",true);
        }
       })
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Can't figure out what I am doing wrong :/

Comment: You need to remove attr required= true when you disable else form give error since feild is not filled

Comment: Else make required=false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little bit hard to understand what you want to happen in what case, but here is the solution for you, tell me if something is missing:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").on("change", function() {
    var formId = $(this).val();
    if (formId == "type1") {
      $('#customer, #extra, #city').prop({"disabled": false, "required": true})
    } else if (formId == "type2") {
      $('#customer, #extra').prop({"disabled": false, "required": true})
      $('#city').prop({"disabled": true, "required": false})
    } else if (formId == "type3") {
      $('#customer').prop({"disabled": false, "required": true})
      $('#extra, #city').prop({"disabled": true, "required": false})
    }
  });
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").on("change", function() {
    var formId = $(this).val();
    if (formId == "type1") {
      $('#customer, #extra, #city').prop({"disabled": false, "required": true})
    } else if (formId == "type2") {
      $('#customer, #extra').prop({"disabled": false, "required": true})
      $('#city').prop({"disabled": true, "required": false})
    } else if (formId == "type3") {
      $('#customer').prop({"disabled": false, "required": true})
      $('#extra, #city').prop({"disabled": true, "required": false})
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="TType">
  <option value="type1">Full</option>
  <option value="type2">Show less</option>
  <option value="type3">Show even less</option>
</select>

<input type="text" maxlength="5" id="customer" name="customer">
<input type="text" maxlength="10" id="extra" name="extra">
<select id="city" name="city">
  <option value="0"> - </option>
  <option value="1">New York</option>
  <option value="2">Chicago</option>
  <option value="3">London</option>
  <option value="4">Athens</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `Show even less` doesn't work as designed. Rigth dropdown is stil enabled

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov When I change the first dropdown to "show less" then the right dropdown is disabled!

Comment: That's true, but `Show even less` should disable rigth input field and dropdown as well. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov In the question he says `type2 it should disable the dropdown menu` he don't say that the input should be

Comment: Sorry, my bad. In question was said `it should disable the dropdown menu and type3 should ALSO disable the extra field`. Other did the same mistake ;)

Answer (score 1):

When the select value changes you can enable all your fields and disabled those field which satisfies your condition.
Refer to below working code-

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").on("change", function() {
    var selectVal = $(this).val();
    $('#customer, #extra, #city').prop("disabled", false)
    if (selectVal == "type2") {
      $('#city').prop("disabled", true)
    } else if (selectVal == "type3") {
      $('#city, #extra').prop("disabled", true)
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="TType">
  <option value="type1">Full</option>
  <option value="type2">Show less</option>
  <option value="type3">Show even less</option>
</select>

<input type="text" maxlength="5" id="customer" name="customer">
<input type="text" maxlength="10" id="extra" name="extra">
<select id="city" name="city">
  <option value="0"> - </option>
  <option value="1">New York</option>
  <option value="2">Chicago</option>
  <option value="3">London</option>
  <option value="4">Athens</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `Show even less` doesn't work as designed. Rigth dropdown is stil enabled

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. I have updated my code. @AndreiSuvorkov

Comment: Looks great now! +1

Answer (score 0):

You have done small mistake.

`$(this).attr("value")` in select will not give you the value. You should use `$(this).val()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("select").on("change", function(){
    var formId = $(this).val();
    if(formId == "type1"){
      $("input[type=text]").each(function(){
        var inputId = $(this).attr("id");
        if(inputId == "customer" || inputId == "extra"){
          $(this).prop("disabled",false);
          $(this).prop("required",true);
        }
      })
      $("select").each(function(){
        var inputId = $(this).attr("id");
        if(inputId == "city"){
          $(this).prop("disabled",false);
          $(this).prop("required",true);
        }
      })
    }else if(formId == "type2"){
      $("select").each(function(){
        var inputId = $(this).attr("id");
        if(inputId == "city"){ 
          $(this).prop("disabled",true);
        }
      })
    }else if(formId == "type3"){
      $("select").each(function(){
        var inputId = $(this).attr("id");
        if(inputId == "city"){ 
          $(this).prop("disabled",true);
        }
      })
      $("input[type=text]").each(function(){
        var inputId = $(this).attr("id");
        if(inputId == "extra"){
          $(this).prop("disabled",true);
        }else{
          $(this).prop("disabled",false);
          $(this).prop("required",true);
        }
       })
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="TType">
    <option value="type1">Full</option>
    <option value="type2">Show less</option>
    <option value="type3">Show even less</option>
</select>

<input type="text" maxlength="5" id="customer" name="customer">
<input type="text" maxlength="10" id="extra" name="extra">
<select id="city" name="city">
    <option value="0"> - </option>
    <option value="1">New York</option>
    <option value="2">Chicago</option>
    <option value="3">London</option>
    <option value="4">Athens</option>
</select>
```

Comment: My guess on why you got a downvote would be because of the messy code. I know it's the OP's code but still.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#TType").on("change", function(){
        var formId = $(this).attr("value");
        if(formId == "type2"){
         $('#city').attr('disabled',true);
          $('#extra').attr('disabled',false);


         }else if(formId == "type3"){
            $('#extra').attr('disabled',true);
            $('#city').attr('disabled',true);

         }else{

            $('#extra').attr('disabled',false);
            $('#city').attr('disabled',false);

        }

    });
});

</script>
```

In above jquery if type1 is selected dropdown and extra  field will be shown ,if type2 dropdown will disabled and in type3 both dropdown and extra will be disabled